# Calling C++ code from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, c++, cgi, emscripten

I have a pretty small code snippet [here](https://github.com/KrzysztofSzewczyk/Esoteric/blob/master/subleq-tools/subleq_asm.cpp). I am **trying to use this code on my website** (preferably in JavaScript). **That's what I tried so far**:

- **Compiling with Emscripten** with no luck (emscripten is complaining about memory size, then when i allow memory growth, it eats just as much memory as computer has, *you are free to try to reproduce it*).
- Trying to **rewrite code in JavaScript** with no luck (This C++ code contains so much C++ only quirks that make my code untranslatable for me).
- **Compiling to WebAssembly**, but the compiler bailed out first time, and the second time generated invalid WebAsm code (that didn't compile).
- **Using CGI** without luck (There is very small amount of information how to do this)
- Compiling program and **running it using PHP** (Child program got killed).

My PHP script source code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("pipe", "w") // stderr is a file to write to
);
$cwd = '/tmp';
$env = array('PHP_SBX' => '1');
$process = proc_open('/var/www/html/gsqas', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
if (is_resource($process)) {
    fwrite($pipes[0],htmlspecialchars($_POST["asmcode"]));
    fclose($pipes[0]);
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);
    fclose($pipes[2]);
    proc_close($process);
}
?>
```

I have no idea what to use and how do I use thing that I choose, to use code snippet that was linked on my website.
This may seems like stupid question but I am struggling with this for a long time.

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't find any of these questions/answers useful for me

Comment: When testing our compilation of the code snippet you provided, what sort of input do you recommend us using?

Comment: If you want heavy duty testing, pick this: https://github.com/KrzysztofSzewczyk/Esoteric/blob/master/subleq/essentials.asm

Comment: It's my OS for subleq arch

Comment: FYI, I thought for sure I'd be able to get this working with Emscripten, but haven't managed to yet.  I may poke at it some more, but thus far, sadly, I agree with your assessment.

Comment: Your code link is broken, I suggest adding the code to the question to avoid this problem in the future